# split div into 2 columns doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-float

Can you please help me, it took me so much time trying to fixe this problem.
i have 2 slider and i need to split each slide into 2 colums. The problem is that the second column which is float: right doesn't show in both sliders .
Here is a code pen that shows the problem [codepen](https://codepen.io/ZinebS/pen/EXLzpz)
thank you

Here is my structure:

```css
    .Dash_map_wrapSlider {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 width: calc(100% - 3rem);
 bottom: calc(-80% + 10rem);
 left: 3rem;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid;
 transition: 0.5s;
 z-index: 1;}

    .Dash_map_wrapSlider:hover{
 bottom: 0rem;
 transition: 0.5s;}

    .Dash_map_wrapSlider:hover{
 bottom: 0rem;
 transition: 0.5s;}
    
    .Dash_map_wrapSliderchoise {
 background: #3E474F;
 box-shadow: 0 .5em 1em #111;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 900;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2rem;
 line-height: 2rem;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;}

    .Dash_map_sumSlide {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 z-index: 10;
 background-color: #fff;
 transition: left 0s .75s;}

    .clsDashMap_sumSlideInput {
 display: none;
 height: 11rem;}

    .clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle {
 position : absolute;
 top:0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2rem;
 left: inherit;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #73b9ff;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.20rem;}

    .clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #666;}

    .clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary {
 position : absolute;
 top: 2rem;
 width: 100%;
 height: 16rem;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: aliceblue;
 text-align: center;}

    .clsDashMap_sumSlideContent {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20rem;
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 color: #000000;}

    [id^="Dash"]:checked + .Dash_map_sumSlide {
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 transition: left .65s ease-out;}

    .Dash_map_wrapSliderchoise label {
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 2rem;
 font-size: 0.75rem;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 0 1em;}

    .clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox {
 margin: auto;
 float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="Dash_map_wrapSlider">
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;width: 100%;">
     <input id="Dash_map_sumSlideSite" class="clsDashMap_sumSlideInput" type="radio" name="slides" checked>
     <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Site " style="float: left;width: 50%;border: 2px solid yellow;">
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle">SITE</div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
        <div class="green led">OK</div>
        <div class="red led">KO</div>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">AlarmesSite</div>
        <canvas id="pieChartAlm" ></canvas>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">TicketsSite</div>
        <canvas id="pieChartTkt" ></canvas>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Alarme" style="float: right;width: 50%; border: 2px solid green;">
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle" >ALARME</div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
        <div class="green led">OK</div>
        <div class="red led">KO</div>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">ALARME1Alm</div>
        <canvas id="pieChartAlm" ></canvas>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Tickets1Alm</div>
        <canvas id="pieChartTkt" ></canvas>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
     </div>
    </div>
     
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;">
     <input id="Dash_map_sumSlideAlarme" class="clsDashMap_sumSlideInput" type="radio" name="slides" checked>   
     <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Site " style="width: 50%;border: 2px solid black;">
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle">TECHNICIEN</div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
        <div class="green led">OK</div>
        <div class="red led">KO</div>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Alarmes2Tech</div>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Tickets2Tech</div>       
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
     </div>
      <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Alarme" style="width: 50%; float: right;border: 2px solid darkturquoise;">
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle" style="position: initial;">ACTION</div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
        <div class="green led">OK</div>
        <div class="red led">KO</div>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">alarme3Act</div>       
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Tickets3Act</div>       
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: most of the elements are using floats, use a clearfix to avoid height collapsing of parent elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **float: right;** give **left: 50%;** to the second column

Comment: for your first slide Site's parent div remove float: left; and give left :0;
i.e, <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Site " style="left:0; width: 50%;border: 2px solid yellow;">

Comment: remove inline left:50%; to slide_Alarme and add this class
[id^="Dash"]:checked + .Dash_map_sumSlide + .Dash_map_sumSlide {
    left: 50%;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out [Bootstrap Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)? I think it is just what you need.

Comment: where i work we unfortunately don't use bootstrap.. we only work with native css